# should there be tags for each type of food stuff?

Tags: discussion, scope, tagging

I've noticed a few tags like `pizza` `meatballs` `eggs`.  Do we want to allow these sort of tags?  or should they be removed?

I can sort of see the use for more generic foods like `eggs` or `pasta` but `meatballs` seems a bit specific.  `fish` might be all right, but do we want `salmon` or `line-caught-orkney-isle-salmon`.  where do we draw the line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that generic food tags are valid. I do think that there has to be a line drawn between what should be accepted and what is not allowed.

I think types of food such as fish, eggs, chicken, etc. should be allowed, as well as very commonly prepared dishes (pizza, sushi, burgers, etc).

When you start to get into specific things like types of fish (salmon, tuna, etc.) or specific types of pasta (spaghetti, rigatoni, etc.), that is where the line needs to be drawn. Those kinds of specific things should be included in the question subject or question text itself.

Comment: yeah I tend to agree with this line of thinking as well.